# React native too much problem using react-native init project

Tags: react-native

I made a few examples using react-native a few weeks back. Now when I tried again the same projects are giving errors. Even almost all GitHub sample projects are giving different errors.

Sometimes errors are Print: Entry, `: CFBundleIdentifier`, Does Not Exist, Then I can run the project using XCode but the same code is not working on Android. After doing some upgrade now I am getting the error `App.js - Cannot read property 'bindings' of null`.

I need to understand why it is so much pain to start react native. I can easily run Project on Expo.

Also, need to know which is the best way to start react native app development.

Below is my react native info:

```
React Native Environment Info:
    System:
      OS: macOS 10.14.2
      CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3615QM CPU @ 2.30GHz
      Memory: 28.59 MB / 8.00 GB
      Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
    Binaries:
      Node: 10.12.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
      Yarn: 1.10.1 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
      npm: 6.4.1 - /usr/local/bin/npm
      Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
    SDKs:
      iOS SDK:
        Platforms: iOS 12.1, macOS 10.14, tvOS 12.1, watchOS 5.1
      Android SDK:
        API Levels: 26, 27
        Build Tools: 25.0.1, 25.0.2, 25.0.3, 26.0.0, 26.0.2, 27.0.3, 28.0.3
        System Images: android-19 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-25 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-27 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-O | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom
    IDEs:
      Android Studio: 3.2 AI-181.5540.7.32.5056338
      Xcode: 10.1/10B61 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
    npmPackages:
      react: 16.0.0 => 16.3.2 
      react-native: ^0.57.7 => 0.56.0-rc.2 
    npmGlobalPackages:
      react-native-cli: 2.0.1
      react-native-git-upgrade: 0.2.7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for Xcode 10 is not fully implemented. thats why you get a `: CFBundleIdentifier` error.

You can look forward for this issues [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19573)

I used this version on xcode 10.1 and it's running well :

```
"react": "16.6.0-alpha.8af6728",
"react-native": "0.57.4"
```